# What's the advantage of mapping a JavaScript string to a "constant"?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, constants, formbuilder

Looking through the Department of Better Technology's [Formbuilder](https://github.com/dobtco/formbuilder) library, I see several cases of strings mapped to capital-letter object properties, as if imitating constants in JavaScript. The following is in [main.coffee](https://github.com/dobtco/formbuilder/blob/gh-pages/src/scripts/main.coffee):

```
mappings:
      SIZE: 'field_options.size'
      UNITS: 'field_options.units'
      LABEL: 'label'
      FIELD_TYPE: 'field_type'
      ...
```

These "constants" are then mostly interpolated in strings that make up views. From [paragraph.coffee](https://github.com/dobtco/formbuilder/blob/gh-pages/src/scripts/fields/paragraph.coffee):

```
view: """
    <textarea class='rf-size-<%= rf.get(Formbuilder.options.mappings.SIZE) %>'></textarea>
  """
```

Is there a performance or architectural advantage in doing this, aside from not having to use literals? Seems like it would be less painstaking, if not faster, just to use the string.

Comment: just a semantic for referencing what is expected to be a constant, similar to naming private methods with an underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poor man's declaration safety.

```
rf.get('field_optons.size')
// => undefined (I assume, depends on rf.get)
rf.get(Formbuilder.optons.mappings.SIZE)
// => TypeError: Cannot read property 'mappings' of undefined
```

A typo in the first case lets your code proceed with a wrong value (`undefined`).

A typo in the second case, unless it is in the last component, will abort your program.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have constants so when you see this it is really more of a code convention used to communicate the intent of a constant. The primary advantage being that you can reference this constant ten times in your code and when you need the value to change, you only need to change it in one spot.

edit: constants are coming to ES6 and are now partially supported in varying browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const